# Unable to auto load Rails 4 monkey patch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, monkeypatching, autoloader

I'm attempting to monkey patch some methods into the Date class and use the Rails autoloader to give me access to them application-wide. When I call these methods, Rails throws undefined method exceptions. Any ideas as to why?

Snippet from application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/lib/patches)
```

/lib/patches/date_patches.rb

```
Date.class_eval do

  def some_method
    true
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3):

Move the file to the config/initializers folder.

Comment: Desperately was looking for this answer.